# Request handling priority in OPC UA

Tags: c#, .net, opc-ua

I'm building an OPCUA Server in Visual C# to be put on a client's machines.

The client wants to make sure that Methods called on the server that have physical consequences have priority on all other requests, for example if a server has 10 active client sessions, and 9 of those clients send a read/write request and one of them sends a move command for a robotic arm, this command should be executed first and the read/write operations should be completed later.

This makes sense for safety reasons: I don't want to wait on 9 read operations before the server gets to the conveyor_belt_stop() command, which was issued to prevent a person from getting injured.

Requests management is handled internally by the Server SDK, so there is no way of implementing custom requests handling policies.

I studied the code of my [SDK of choice](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/tree/master/Libraries), and I saw that it [adds requests to a Queue object](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/blob/master/Libraries/Opc.Ua.Server/Server/RequestManager.cs#L120) and uses worker threads to satisfy the requests. Given that Queue is a FIFO queue makes it impossible to somehow rearrange the request to favor those that I want.

For now I plan to use the sample client to benchmark the latency of this queue mechanism and trust the OPCUA devs that this is the right approach, but I would like to have a better answer for my client.

Does OPCUA provide a way to define priorities for the request handling from either the Client or Server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does OPCUA provide a way to define priorities for the request handling from either the Client or Server side?

No, it doesn't.

But I think you've misunderstood the implementation of the SDK you linked to. It does not queue requests and process them one-by-one. The object you link to is a Dictionary, not a Queue, and it's used for other bookkeeping purposes.

That said, you could consider keeping 2 sessions open, and using one of those sessions as your "high priority" session where you only issue method calls or other operations your application considers high priority.

Comment: You are right, the Queue<T> was from another place in the code. I like the session idea, but I don't see a way to specify on either ends that a Session has higher priority than other Sessions. Can you be more specific?

Comment: There is no session priority either. As the client, you would just only make “high priority” service calls on one of them. Ultimately, though, this all depends on the implementation details of the server. You don’t have the level of control you’re wishing for. I suspect you are worrying about this prematurely, though.

Comment: I agree that I don't have that level of control, I was hoping there was some aspect of OPCUA that I hadn't yet studied that allowed what I was looking for, but it seems that OPCUA simply isn't built for that, unless one would start from the core libraries and make a custom Server SDK, which would be a tremendous amount of work, not to talk about the maintenance.